# Check if there is a character that appears 5 consecutive times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making an `isWin` function that checks if there is a character that appears 5 consecutive times (either horizontally, vertically or diagonally).

I've tried using this  code:

```
#VERTICAL WIN
count = 0
for row in range(1,grid_height):
    print(row)
    for col in range(1,grid_width):
        print(col)
        if grid[row][col-2] == p_char:
            count += 1
            if count == 5:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
            continue

#HORIZONAL WIN
count=0
for  col in range(0,grid_width):
    for row in range(0,grid_height):
        if grid[row][col-2] == p_char:
            count += 1
            if count == 5:
                return True
        else:
            count = 0
            continue
```

And this is where i place it in my main program:

```
def play():
     grid,grid_height,grid_width,p1_name,p1_char,p2_name,p2_char=getGameSettings()
    displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width)
    print('WELCOME TO THE GAME!')

    playerA = Player(p1_name, PLAYING)
    playerB = Player(p2_name, WAITING)
    grid=[]

    for row in range(grid_height): # FOR ROW
        z =[]
        for col in range(grid_width): # FOR COLUMN
            z.append(" ")
        grid.append(z)

    numColFull = 0
    turn=0
    while turn < grid_height*grid_width:
        player = playerA
        if turn % 2 == 0 : #IF TURN IS AN ODD NUMBER, THEN IT IS player 1's turn, IF TURN IS EVEN, THEN IT IS player 2's turn
            p_char= p1_char
            player = playerA
            playerA.setState(PLAYING)
            playerB.setState(WAITING)
        else :
            p_char= p2_char
            player = playerB
            playerB.setState(PLAYING)
            playerA.setState(WAITING)

        print(".................................................. ")
        print("User to play : ", player.playerInfo() , " SEQ : ", str(turn)) # TO COUNT THE TOTAL NUMBER OF MOVES
        print(".................................................. ")

        if numColFull == grid_width: #THE isDRAW function but embedded into the main function
            # IF the numColFull is equal to gridwidth, it means that all of the columns has been occupied, meaning
            #that every space has already been occupied, thus, game is over. 
            print('........All spaces had been occupied...........')
            print('................THE GAME IS DRAW...............')
            print('.................GAME OVER.....................')
            break
        else:
            while True:
                try:
                    move=int(input('Enter your move: '))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Please enter a valid input.')
                if move < 1 or move > grid_width:
                    print('Please enter a valid input.')
                    continue
                break

            updateGrid(grid,grid_height-1,grid_width,move,p_char)

            while True:
                if grid[0][move-2] == p_char: #IF THE TOP ROW OF A COLUMN HAS A PIECE IN IT, IT MEANS ITS ALREADY FULL 
                    displayGrid(grid,grid_height, grid_width)
                    print('Column is full. Please choose another column for the next move.')
                    numColFull += 1
                    break
                elif isWin == True: #IF THE IF CONDITION DIDNT HOLD TRUE, THEN THE FUNCTION CONTINUES AS USUAL
                    print(player, 'WINS!!!')
                    ('.................GAME OVER.....................')
                else:    
                    displayGrid(grid,grid_height, grid_width)

                break #GOES BACK TO THE THE WHILE CONDITION

        turn += 1 #INCREMENTS 1 TO TURN SO IT WILL SWITCH BETWEEN BEING ODD AND EVEN
```

And this is my grid:

```
def displayGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width): 
    for row in range(1,grid_height):
        #print(row) #for checking
        for col in range(grid_width):
            print("|", end="")
            print(str(grid[row-1][col-1]),end = "")
        print("|")
    print(" "+" ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, grid_width+1)]))
    return grid

def updateGrid(grid,grid_height,grid_width,move,p_char):
    for i in range(1,grid_height+1):
        print(i)
        #print(i) #ROW COUNTING STARTS FROM 1 
        if grid[grid_height-i][move-2] == " ":
            grid[grid_height-i][move-2]= p_char #REPLACES THE " " TO THE CURRENT PLAYER'S CHARACTER (p_char)
        else:
            continue
        break

    return grid
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are writing Five In a Row? But anyway, this code should work:

```
def isWin():
    # Horizontal
    for i in range(grid_height):
        for j in range(grid_width - 4):
            if set(grid[i][j:j+5]) == {p_char}:
                return True
    # Vertical
    for i in range(grid_height - 4):
        for j in range(grid_width):
            if { grid[i+k][j] for k in range(5) } == {p_char}:
                return True
    # Diagonal
    for i in range(grid_height - 4):
        for j in range(grid_width - 4):
            if { grid[i+k][j+k] for k in range(5) } == {p_char}:
                return True
    return False

# Simplified
def isWin():
    return any(set(grid[i][j:j+5]) == {p_char} for i in range(grid_height) for j in range(grid_width - 4)) or \
           any({ grid[i+k][j] for k in range(5) } == {p_char} for i in range(grid_height - 4) for j in range(grid_width)) or \
           any({ grid[j+k][i+k] for k in range(5) } == {p_char} for i in range(grid_width - 4) for j in range(grid_width - 4))
```

Since set cannot have duplicates, using expressions like `{ grid[j+k][i+k] for k in range(5) }` will put 5 consecutive pieces into a set. If there are 5 consecutive `p_char`s, then the set will become `{p_char}`.

Comment: It says that k is underfined?

Comment: @Gatts Ah sorry, fixed.

Comment: @Gatts Ah wait I need to refix it.

Comment: It doesn't work? Is  == 1  should be equal to the p_char?

Comment: There is  no error, it simply doesn't do what its supposed to do. Even  i have a 5 consecutive in a row or a column, it doesnt print (player, 'WINS'). Could you check my main function if i implemented it right?

Comment: @Gatts Sorry but there are a lot of things that I don't get from your code. That's the reason why I am starting a new one. For example, why does your range starts with 1? Why is it `col-2`?

Comment: I don't really understand it exactly but i've tried different values for which my piece will be placed on the desired column. And it basically only works in that configuration

Comment: @Gatts Can I see your test case? It works on my side.

Comment: How will i show it? Can i see your whole code?  I might have implemented the isWin function wrong.

Comment: For example, how you put the pieces? Like a string of `'00001\n00001\n00001\n00001\n00001\n'` where `'1'` is the `p_char`.

Comment: I dont understand, sir.

Comment: Sorry, can you show me the grid that `isWin` doesn't work?

Comment: I didn't know how will i show it to you here so i just uploaded an image.  https://imgur.com/ZeFQ3ku Basically, even if p_char appears consecutively for 5 times, it still doesnt print(player, 'Wins')

Comment: Does `isWin` check for one side or two sides? And is `p_char` changing?

Comment: What do you mean? isWin should basically return True if in any part of the grid, p_char appears 5 times consecutively (whether horizontally, vertically  or  diagonally). I'm sorry, im not sure if i answered  your question

Comment: Never mind, I've found the issue. Sorry give me a second.

Comment: @Gatts My bad. I was overconfident on this one. Updated! Can you check it?

Comment: What does it mean when you put p_char in {}?

Comment: It is still not working, maybe its got something to do with how i made my grid?

Comment: Yes my solution only works if your grid contain the pieces only. Otherwise please first check if the value of `p_char` is what you want, then post an image of the case where it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes its supposed  to be p_char. my p_char depends on who  of the two  player is playing.

Comment: Then can you show the content of your grid? Or can you post an image of the case?

Comment: What do you mean the content of my grid?

Comment: Do `print(grid)`.

Comment: This is my grid  https://imgur.com/ut3VDC7. Basically, i will ask the current player for his move (the column he wants to put in his piece) and i will update the grid and then i will ask the next player, then update the grid again, and so on

Comment: Ah it seems that your grid is not purely consisting of the pieces but with the visualization elements. Remove those should work. It is bad practice to combine visualization with data as this makes it hard to handle data. If you need better visualization, please write a new function to convert your grid to the format you want.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200057/discussion-on-answer-by-seaky-lone-check-if-there-is-a-character-that-appears-5).